# Is it possible to remove clock input variable from the AIGER output?

Tags: yosys

Consider the example:

```
read_verilog ./tests/simple/fsm.v
synth -flatten -top fsm_test
abc -g AND
write_aiger -ascii -symbols hoho.aag
```

The resulting AIGER file contains input variable `clk`, which is dangling.
Is it possible to avoid introducing such clock input into AIGER?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatically. The following options exist:

1. Simply use the SystemVerilog $global_clock feature to avoid having a clock input at all. Use `always @($global_clock)` instead of `always @(posedge clk)` and then remove the `clk` input from your design.
2. Remove the clock input near the end of your synthesis script. I.e. right before calling `write_aiger` call something like `delete -input fsm_test/clk`. This will turn the clock signal into a dangling wire internal to the module. You should avoid doing that before running a lot of optimization commands, or you risk Yosys optimizing away all your FFs. But doing that near the end of your script should be fine.
3. You can combine 2. with mapping your FFs to `$ff`/`$_FF_` cells (the kind of FF cells generated by `$global_clock`-blocks). The advantage of this approach is that it makes the clk wire truly unused, so there is no risk of optimizations messing with your FFs because they have an undriven clock input. I've now added a `dff2ff.v` techmap file in commit e7a984a that simplifies this a bit.

Script for option 2:

```
read_verilog ./tests/simple/fsm.v
synth -flatten -top fsm_test
abc -g AND
delete -input fsm_test/clk
write_aiger -ascii -symbols hoho.aag
```

Script for option 3 (requires Yosys git commit e7a984a or later):

```
read_verilog ./tests/simple/fsm.v
hierarchy -top fsm_test
proc
techmap -map +/dff2ff.v
delete fsm_test/clk
synth -flatten 
abc -g AND
write_aiger -ascii -symbols hoho.aag
```